# How to toggle different css class on button in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a button with two different css classes isActiveStyle and isNotActiveStyle

I am attempting to trigger between these two classes by clicking by this code

```
              <button
            className={({ isActive }) =>
              isActive ? isActiveStyle : isNotActiveStyle
            }
          >
```

Since I am using typescript I am getting error of :

> Type '({ isActive }: { isActive: any; }) => "flex items-center gap-x-2
> p-2 w-[100%] transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out
> hover:bg-[#F1F1F1] font-light" | "flex items-center gap-x-2 p-2
> w-[100%] transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out bg-[#F1F1F1]
> font-bold"' is not assignable to type 'string'.

isActive is not declared anywhere else in this component?
How can I fix this code?
Thanks

Comment: You are returning function object instead of a string

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to declare a function, just use a `ternary` operator

```
<button className={isActive ? isActiveStyle : isNotActiveStyle}>
```